# recursion: make changes with fewest coins

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I'm studing the data structure and algorithm in python. Here is the classic problem of recursion involving making change with the fewest coins. Here are the codes.
What I do not understand is line 2. why do we need `minCoins = change`? what does line 8-9 mean? can anyone helo explain that? thank you very much for help!

```
def recMC(coinValueList,change):
   minCoins = change
   if change in coinValueList:
     return 1
   else:
      for i in [c for c in coinValueList if c <= change]:
         numCoins = 1 + recMC(coinValueList,change-i)
         if numCoins < minCoins:
            minCoins = numCoins
   return minCoins

print(recMC([1,5,10,25],63))
```

Comment: What is the required solution? An amount of coins or a dictionary with the amount each type of coin. Also, this code gives me an infinite loop. I can't explain the working of a code that does not work. Would you like me to write a new solution and explain that one?

Comment: It's not actually an infinite loop but just a super inefficient algorithm

Answer (score 1):

`minCoins = change`: `minCoins` is initialized with the value of `change` which is the maximum value that `recMC` can return as the minimum value of a coin is 1, assuming integer values of coins.

`if change in coinValueList: return 1`: base case 1 - if some coin has a value of that of `change` we just need to grab this 1 coin, thus returning 1

`for i in [c for c in coinValueList if c <= change]:`:
The function then loops through all possible values of 1 single coin to

`numCoins = 1 + recMC(coinValueList,change-i)`: deduct the coin value `i` from `change`, add 1 coin to the number of coins needed which is recursively calculated for the leftover change (`change-i`). This works inductively from the *2* base cases

`if numCoins < minCoins: minCoins = numCoins` inside this loop effectively assigns the smallest number of coins possible to `minCoins`

If `change` still had the initialized value of `minCoins` (implying no value `c` in `coinValueList` satisfies `c <= change`), this means that the number of coins needed is also the value of `change`, i.e. `change` 1-unit coins. This is base case 2 that is based on the pre-condition that the coin with value 1 is always available.