# Given an integer array and a value N. Represent N as a sum of minimum number of elements of the array. How to approach this problem?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Suppose, given an array `A = {1, 3, 10, 11, 20}` and a value `N`. Now, my task is to represent `N` as a sum of minimum number of elements of the array `A`.

Note: There might be one or more occurrence of an element of the array in the representation. But, the total length of the representation must be minimum.

Let `N = 5`. Here the answer would be `{1, 1, 3}`. Here the length of the representation is 3. There is no way I can get shorter length representation. So, it is the answer for `N = 5`.

Another example: If `N = 8` then the shortest representation is `{1, 1, 3, 3}`.

I think this problem should be solved using Dynamic Programming. But, I can't come up with any idea. How should I approach this?

Comment: @GBlodgett That is an approach that only works for very specific cases. For example, if you want to represent `6` and you have `[1, 3, 4]`, your approach will say that the answer is `4 + 1 + 1`, but the correct answer is actually `3 + 3`.

Comment: @JohnFeminella Yes I just now realized

Comment: Possible duplicate of [recursion: make changes with fewest coins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40088908/recursion-make-changes-with-fewest-coins)

Comment: This is the problem of making change with minimal quantity of coins.  This is documented well on line.  Now that you have some classic keywords, you should be able to research a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like homework, so I won't give the whole answer away, but here's a strategy one can use.

This problem is a bit like **making change when you want to give back the minimum number of coins**.

For example, if you have an infinite number of `{1¢, 5¢, 25¢}` coins and you want to give 37¢ in change, you'd do that by providing 25¢ + 5¢ + 5¢ + 1¢ + 1¢, **for a total of 5 coins**.

Now, what if you also had 7¢ coins available, so that your selection was from `{1¢, 5¢, 7¢, 25¢}`? Now you can do 25¢ + 7¢ + 5¢, **for a total of 3 coins**.

This might suggest that we can work backwards from the biggest coin size to the smallest one. **But that's not correct.** Consider what happens if we have `{1¢, 3¢, 4¢}` and we want to represent 6¢. We'd provide `4¢ + 1¢ + 1¢` for a total of 3 coins — *but the shortest answer is actually `3¢ + 3¢`*.

So the naive/greedy approach won't always get us the right answer here; we'll need to use something like dynamic programming.

A dynamic programming approach could take a number of forms, but it needs to use two key insights:

- *Optimal substructure:* The way you make change for x¢ is useful for understanding the way you make change for x¢ + n¢.
- *Overlapping subproblems:* The way you make change for x¢ might be computed a number of different times when considering values larger than x¢. Can you reuse those calculations to avoid doing the work more than once?

One approach is outlined [here](http://www.columbia.edu/~cs2035/courses/csor4231.F07/dynamic.pdf) if you're stuck. Hope that helps!

Comment: I have been able to count the minimum number of coins needed for the change using dynamic programming.  How can I print those coins?